# from /user?u=Username to => /user/username

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a possibility. Change the link like this:

```
www.example.com/user?u=Username to => www.example.com/user/Username
```

But still with PHP to recognize by which user it is.
Best without extra pages to create?

Comment: Look like htaccess, you should go check them, look for Url rewriting !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: click the link on my comment above

Comment: First of all, you need to rewrite URL from htaccess. Then from your expected URL, You can extract the last part by using explode("/", $url). you can have the username for use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewriting - PHP + Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268618/url-rewriting-php-apache)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: The question have many dupes. you should have checked some examples here on so before asking

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sorry I had no idea what I had to look for.

Comment: ok understandable, look at all the links provided above and see, if you can be able to learn from em

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above you should use Url rewriting : 
For exemple put this in the root of your website under the name `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteRule ^/?user/([A-Za-z]+)$  user.php?u=$1  [L]
```

Comment: Then please mark the question as solved by my answer.By the way, the "?" before the "/" mean that the "/" is optional :)

Comment: Done! Thx a Lot  kaldoran and the rest!                                                      Little hint: If you have Relative Paths you have to add a ../ Because the file now thinks it is in the orderner user

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help all together. This has worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?user/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ user.php?u=$1
```

Little hint:
If you have Relative Paths you have to add a ../
Because the file now thinks it is in the folder user